# JAXB ignore transient fields without annotations

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm using JAXB on a JDK 5 based app.

The XML marshaling is a side feature, so the annotations on the POJO model are excluded. The fields that should be excluded are `transient` (the java keyword).

Is there a way to configure the `Marshaler` to ignore those fields.

Here's the code I use to serialize my POJOs to XML:

```java
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(BasePOJO.class, target.getClass());

JAXBElement<WsResponse> model = new JAXBElement<BasePOJO>(
        new QName(target.getClass().getSimpleName()), 
        (Class<BasePOJO>) target.getClass(), 
        (BasePOJO)target
    );

Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(model, os);
```

A sample POJO I need to serialize:

```java
public class APOJO extends BasePOJO {
  private Long id;
  private String desc;
  private transient String aFieldToIgnore;

  //and the accessors[...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to do this without using the `@XmlTransient` annotation on your fields.

The only real customisations you can do are using binding files or in-line bindings in your XSD.

Check the reference for what is possible: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html